# Sum the values ​of a list of nested dictionaries that have the same key

Tags: python

I want to sum a list of nested dictionaries with the same key. This is the list:

```
[{'CAG': {'PG': 4, 'punti': 0, 'Gol fatti': 0, 'Gol subiti': 3, 'Differenza reti': -3, 'Vittorie': 0, 'Pareggi': 0, 'Sconfitte': 1}}, 
 {'ROM': {'PG': 4, 'punti': 3, 'Gol fatti': 3, 'Gol subiti': 0, 'Differenza reti': 3, 'Vittorie': 1, 'Pareggi': 0, 'Sconfitte': 0}}, 
 {'CAG': {'PG': 4, 'punti': 3, 'Gol fatti': 1, 'Gol subiti': 0, 'Differenza reti': 1, 'Vittorie': 1, 'Pareggi': 0, 'Sconfitte': 0}}, 
 {'ROM': {'PG': 4, 'punti': 0, 'Gol fatti': 0, 'Gol subiti': 1, 'Differenza reti': -1, 'Vittorie': 0, 'Pareggi': 0, 'Sconfitte': 1}}, 
 {'CAG': {'PG': 4, 'punti': 0, 'Gol fatti': 0, 'Gol subiti': 1, 'Differenza reti': -1, 'Vittorie': 0, 'Pareggi': 0, 'Sconfitte': 1}}]
```

I would like to check if they have the same primary key (i.e 'CAG') and then sum the corresponding values.

Final result:

```
[{'ROM': {'PG': 8, 'punti': 3, 'Gol fatti': 3, 'Gol subiti': 1, 'Differenza reti': 2, 'Vittorie': 1, 'Pareggi': 0, 'Sconfitte': 1}}, 
 {'CAG': {'PG': 12, 'punti': 3, 'Gol fatti': 1, 'Gol subiti': 4, 'Differenza reti': -3, 'Vittorie': 1, 'Pareggi': 0, 'Sconfitte': 2}}]
```

Comment: Yes! If you want to do it, just do it. You don't need to ask us for permission.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Could you maybe specify how we could help you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class supports addition which would make this quite easy. Combining that with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of `Counter`s we can get:

```py
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

l = [{'CAG': {'PG': 4, 'punti': 0, 'Gol fatti': 0, 'Gol subiti': 3, 'Differenza reti': -3, 'Vittorie': 0, 'Pareggi': 0, 'Sconfitte': 1}},
 {'ROM': {'PG': 4, 'punti': 3, 'Gol fatti': 3, 'Gol subiti': 0, 'Differenza reti': 3, 'Vittorie': 1, 'Pareggi': 0, 'Sconfitte': 0}},
 {'CAG': {'PG': 4, 'punti': 3, 'Gol fatti': 1, 'Gol subiti': 0, 'Differenza reti': 1, 'Vittorie': 1, 'Pareggi': 0, 'Sconfitte': 0}},
 {'ROM': {'PG': 4, 'punti': 0, 'Gol fatti': 0, 'Gol subiti': 1, 'Differenza reti': -1, 'Vittorie': 0, 'Pareggi': 0, 'Sconfitte': 1}},
 {'CAG': {'PG': 4, 'punti': 0, 'Gol fatti': 0, 'Gol subiti': 1, 'Differenza reti': -1, 'Vittorie': 0, 'Pareggi': 0, 'Sconfitte': 1}}]

counter = defaultdict(Counter)
for d in l:
    for key, value in d.items():
        counter[key] += Counter(value)

print(counter)
```

Using a `defaultdict` we create an empty `Counter` for each potential key ('CAG'/'ROM'). Then for each key we encounter we add up its counter with a `Counter` from the values.

The output will be:

```
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'CAG': Counter({'PG': 12, 'Gol subiti': 4, 'punti': 3, 'Sconfitte': 2, 'Gol fatti': 1, 'Vittorie': 1}), 'ROM': Counter({'PG': 8, 'punti': 3, 'Gol fatti': 3, 'Differenza reti': 2, 'Vittorie': 1, 'Gol subiti': 1, 'Sconfitte': 1})})
```

And to get a list output a simple manipulation will do:

```
print([{key: dict(counts)} for key, counts in counter.items()])
```

Will give:

```
[{'CAG': {'PG': 12, 'Gol subiti': 4, 'Sconfitte': 2, 'punti': 3, 'Gol fatti': 1, 'Vittorie': 1}}, 
 {'ROM': {'PG': 8, 'punti': 3, 'Gol fatti': 3, 'Differenza reti': 2, 'Vittorie': 1, 'Gol subiti': 1, 'Sconfitte': 1}}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I would always like to keep the keys even when the value is 0 or negative.